# Can I turn on WebGL in the ubuntu-touch web browsers?

Tags: graphics, ubuntu-touch, 3d, webgl, webbrowser-app

Apparently, the reason for geogebra not displaying its 3D mode in my Ubuntu-touch device is that the browser is not using webGL, somehow. It happens with both Firefox and the default browser. What can I do to this respect?

Comment: Try a WebGL test page like [the one from webgl.org](https://get.webgl.org/).

Comment: Thanks, Chai. Actually, I had already tried that with negative results: apparently they support webgl but it is deactivated somehow.